# Source Depot Client Error while doing PFGold Enlistment

Tags: source-depot

I was doing enlistment for PFGold on my SAW VM and observed the below error:

Source Depot client error:
Connection with partner closed unexpectedly.
RpcTransport: partial message read
TCP receive from [2001:4898:2001:fe16:e5e1:267a:4f7d:645] failed.
read: socket: WSAECONNABORTED

I was expecting to complete the enlistment as per the docuemntation
https://eng.ms/docs/products/autopilot/autopilot/apgold

Comment: This is the public StackOverflow. You should ask your question on the internal StackOverflow.

Comment: How can I go to internal StackOverflow?

Comment: aka.ms/stackoverflow